# JAVA - JAXB Unmarshalling Error

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am facing below UnMarshalling error. The error is for the tag "er-response". There is er-response tag in the rsponse recieved but i the error is for the namespace. Surprisingly, the JAVA code generated from the xsd doesn't have this namespace ({localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common)

Also, there is a seperate XSD which contains the namespace ({localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common) but this is not used and it doesn't have an er-response element.

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response"). Expected elements are <{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response>,<{}full-account-v2>,<{}full-accounts-response>,<{}selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-transactions-v2>;

SCHEMA :-

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:common="http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/common"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/common"
        schemaLocation="../common/pa_common.xsd" />
    <!-- An er-response encapsulates all response packets that are returned 
        by ER's REST interface. -->
    <xs:element name="er-response">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- A generic payload will have wrap all xml fragments that are sent 
                    to the REST interface. The payload type defines this generic payload. -->
                <xs:element name="payload" type="common:payloadType" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="sub-id" use="optional">
                <xs:simpleType>
                <!-- by setting it to integer not int, we get an Object not a primitive type.
                This means jaxb will not marshall the value if it's not been set -->
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="version" use="optional">
                <xs:simpleType>
                <!-- by setting it to integer not int, we get an Object not a primitive type.
                This means jaxb will not marshall the value if it's not been set 
                (which we need for backwards compatibility)     -->
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <!-- The id and sub-id fields identify the type of response that is encapsulated 
                in the payload. The client application will be able to use these values to 
                bind the payload to the appropriate java object model. -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

RESPONSE :-

```
<er-response id="100053">
   <payload>
      <modify-usergroup-reponse>
         <success>true</success>
         <reason-code>
            <code>0</code>
            <sub-code>0</sub-code>
            <name>OK</name>
         </reason-code>
      </modify-usergroup-reponse>
   </payload>
</er-response>
```

Comment: Are you using SOAP namespaces by any chance?

Comment: I am using jersey framework to unmarshal. I am calling a Rest Api with xml as transport.